# Big Query (SQL) Add one month to the date (Issue) - (Data Studio)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Currently, I'm adding an extra month this way:

```
DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS pDate
```

I'm trying to compare two values by month, by using the same date range. So I made another custom field with date +1 month and when I use it...it missing days with 31.

June 30 +1 month = July 31 and as I using custom field... it missing fields where date with 31

**EDITING  v1.0**

I have a database for a year, each day is presented.

As example:

```
01012018
....
31012018
01022018
...
28022018
```

I need to compare two time period and to solve this issue I create a custom field which takes the date and add +1 month, so after in Data studio (could be in any over platform) can compare 25-30January with 25-30February, the issue is when I add 1 month to the date 30012018 it becomes 30022018 (WHich as you know does not exist)

Anyway, I'm sticking with this idea, but maybe there are any other ways of doing this? WIll repeat again, I need to compare the same date but from different month - 15th January -20 January WITH 15th February - 20th February, but again issue where 30th-31st appears

Comment: The real problem here as I see it is that adding one month has boundary condition problems.  How do you want to handle the fact that June has 30 days, February 28 (29), and July 31 days?  Answer this, and maybe someone can give you some SQL for it.

Comment: @Pentium10 Sorry for my English, issues are with missis dates (I'm not sure how to handle this, this is the sad point), another issue is that there  are 31 days in August and 30 Days in September and I add 31082018 +1 month it return 31092018 (which does not exist)

Comment: as I mentioned try going away from fixed days, and rather use 3rd monday of the month, that's more accurate to compare

Comment: Sample data with desired results would help.  That is, a *text* table with examples of dates and what you want to return.  I can't figure out what you want -- a new date, a valid comparison, or something else.

Comment: @Platinum10 Have a look, I have updated my question, p.s. ( for the job I need to compare from 29th to 29th of another month)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have a look I have updated my question

Comment: Sorry, @NANA, so what is the issue? What do you want exactly? To compare 2 dates? And you add 1 month to the first date in order to compare? Why you can't compare without adding any month? And, when you add a month using DATE_ADD( date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) with February, why it doesn't work four you? I tested: **SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE "2009-1-30", INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as five_days_later;** and the result is "2009-02-28" which looks cool.

Comment: @NANA - i think you should provide example of actual query that you are trying to make work. even if it is not working and produces errors  - this will help us to understand what exactly you are trying t achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to compare two time period ...

*Unfortunately, you question still does not show what exactly your use case - so below is attempt to give you an idea based on generalization of what I see in question*

In below (for BigQuery Standard SQL):

- the `project.dataset.table` is your real table with dates and metrics you want to compare.
- `days_range` and `months_range` - allow you to set range or days and months respectively without doing any changes in main SELECT statement

---

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH days_range AS (
  SELECT 15 start_day, 20 end_day
), months_range AS (
  SELECT 1 start_month, 4 end_month
)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(MIN(day_date) AS STRING), ' - ', CAST(MAX(day_date) AS STRING)) interval_days,
  SUM(metric) interval_metric
FROM `project.dataset.table`, days_range, months_range
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_day AND end_day
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_month AND end_month
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(day_date, MONTH)
-- ORDER BY 1
```

To play with above you can use below script that mimics your real table by generating days for year of 2018 along with random metrics

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT day_date, CAST(100 * RAND() AS INT64) metric
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')) day_date 
), days_range AS (
  SELECT 15 start_day, 20 end_day
), months_range AS (
  SELECT 1 start_month, 4 end_month
)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(MIN(day_date) AS STRING), ' - ', CAST(MAX(day_date) AS STRING)) interval_days,
  SUM(metric) interval_metric
FROM `project.dataset.table`, days_range, months_range
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_day AND end_day
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_month AND end_month
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(day_date, MONTH)
ORDER BY 1
```

with result as

```sql
Row     interval_days               interval_metric  
1       2018-01-15 - 2018-01-20     244  
2       2018-02-15 - 2018-02-20     235  
3       2018-03-15 - 2018-03-20     204  
4       2018-04-15 - 2018-04-20     355
```

if you want to check how same script will 'behave' for 28-30-31 days  - try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT day_date, CAST(100 * RAND() AS INT64) metric
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')) day_date 
), days_range AS (
  SELECT 25 start_day, 31 end_day
), months_range AS (
  SELECT 1 start_month, 4 end_month
)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(MIN(day_date) AS STRING), ' - ', CAST(MAX(day_date) AS STRING)) interval_days,
  SUM(metric) interval_metric
FROM `project.dataset.table`, days_range, months_range
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_day AND end_day
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day_date) BETWEEN start_month AND end_month
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(day_date, MONTH)
ORDER BY 1
```

with result

```sql
Row     interval_days               interval_metric  
1       2018-01-25 - 2018-01-31     364  
2       2018-02-25 - 2018-02-28     227  
3       2018-03-25 - 2018-03-31     311  
4       2018-04-25 - 2018-04-30     308
```

---

Hope this will help you to move forward